# How to use boost::numpy::from_data in boost-numpy library

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost, multidimensional-array

I'm using boost.numpy and trying to make ndarray wrapper. I'm trying to send ndarray from python to c++ and c++ to python. When I sent ndarray from python to c++, the problem has occured. What is incorrect?

```
+++mod2.cpp+++
1 #include"boost/numpy.hpp"
2 #include<iostream>
3 
4 boost::numpy::ndarray test(boost::numpy::ndarray a){
5   boost::numpy::ndarray b = a;
6  int arr[]={5,4,3,2,1};
7   b =      boost::numpy::from_data(arr,boost::numpy::dtype::get_builtin<int>(),
8       boost::python::make_tuple(5),boost::python::make_tuple(sizeof(int)),boost::python::object());
9    std::cout << "In mymod2.cpp:" <<
10      boost::python::extract < char const * > (boost::python::str(b)) << std::endl ; 
11   return b;
12 }
13 
14 BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymod2){
15   boost::numpy::initialize();
16   boost::python::def("test",test);
17 }               

+++demo.py+++
1 import numpy
2 import mymod2
3 
4 Mat1 = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=numpy.int32)
5 print("In demo.py:",Mat1)                                                                                         
6 Mat2=mymod2.test(Mat1)
7 print("In demo.py:",Mat2)

+++Output+++
In demo.py: [1 2 3 4 5]
In mymod2.cpp:[5 4 3 2 1]
In demo.py: [        0        48 430934944     32509         3]
```

Answer (score 1):

int arr[]={5,4,3,2,1} is on the stack. from_data references the data passed to it, it does not copy it, so your returning stack addresses in the ndarray. Using new means this issue is avoided, as the memory is on the heap, but now the data is leaking. You need to use the owner parameter to manage the tidying of the memory when the ndarry is freed.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand why, but if you use:

```
int *arr;
arr = new int[5];
arr[0] = 5;
arr[1] = 4;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 2;
arr[4] = 1;
```

instead of `int arr[]={5,4,3,2,1}`, it will return the right array to python code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new reference to the array before returning it with

```
np::ndarray new_b = b.copy();
```